# Make sure .bak-file is ready after MS database backup

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, vb.net, database-backups

I tried to copy a .bak-file to the local machine directly after the backup on the server finished.

I never had any problems with that while testing and debugging, but after deployment I got a lot of FileNotFoundExceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that, especiall if you do the backup on an other machine, the backupfile needs a little extra time to be ready.

Waiting a little before starting the moving-process solved the problem for me.

1. Do Backup on Server
2. WaitForFileToExist(string); (Make sure the path is right, otherwise it will of course never return)
3. Move File

   ```
   public void WaitForFileToExist(String path) {
       while (File.Exists(path) == false) {
           System.Threading.Sleep(10);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Waiting only 3 seconds can be a problem if the same opeeration is ran on a slower machine.  You should find a way that doesn't put the `Thread` to sleep.  While your approach works ( for now ) its not actually the correct way.

Comment: You are right, I replaced the waiting method.

This may be more save for more different cases.

Comment: Its better but I would haved used a mutex for this sort of thing, using async thread, waiting until the thread to finish.